# How to TDD for CouchDB with CouchApp?

Tags: tdd, workflow, couchdb, couchapp

Recently I've discovered CouchDB. I want to use CouchApp to build a flash games site. It looks like a perfect fit 'cause this kind of a site is totally document based with a bit of binary attachments.

The only thing I need to learn before I start is how to TDD with CouchApp/CouchDB. I couldn't google any workflow tutorial and I'm not experienced enough to adapt any existing server-side JS workflow to the CouchDB environment.

Your suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this and found [jsunit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) and Jasmine.

I settled on jsunit for familiarity and because I had a book with some examples in it (yeah, I know a real scientific decision process).

I got what I wanted out of it, but an not entirely happy about the way of working in a browser as a test runner. I need to look at some ways to automate it in my build process.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try Jasmine. It looks like the result of several years of real-world experience and also I'm familiar with BDD.

Comment: Btw I now use Jasmine for all my client side JavaScript projects